# EntityFrameworkCore reading data using reflection - how to create DbSet when type unknown

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am working with a .Net 6 Console application where I need to read data from tables in a custom *DbContext* using *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore*

I have added the entities to the model in *OnModelCreating()* and can get them back using a call to

```
var entity = ctx.Model.GetEntityTypes().FirstOrDefault(e => e.FullName().InfexOf(tableName) >= 0);
```

Given that, how to I retrieve a list of data, for example *entity.ToList()* - the type returned for entity is IEntityType?.

As an alternate (and my preferred way if possible), I have created an array of tables using reflection (they all inherit from BaseTable), they are stored as a list.

I would like to create a DbSet<> using DbContext.Set() so that I can use Find(), AsNoTracking() and other such commands (including write operations).

I have the following:-

```
 IQueryable<Object>dbSet = (IQueryable<Object>)ctx
                                                .GetType()
                                                .GetMethod("Set",1,Type.EmptyTypes)
                                                .MakeGenericMethod(t)   
                                                .Invoke(ctx, null);
```

Which allows me to do something like dbSet.ToList(), but I would really like to cast it to a DbSet.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make such a conversion?

(I am reading only a few records from sets of tables and then writing data back to a different database (with the same tables).

Update: *Another way of thinking about this:  I am iterating across a collection of tables. I need to pull out the PK and two other columns (for which I have the name of at runtime) - if the value of column 1 contains a specific value, I need to update the value of column 2 *

Comment: EF Core is all about loading / storing objects. If you don't actually care about objects, you'll probably find it easier to just use raw sql tools.

Comment: Do you have an example?  I have updated my original post with a clarification of what I am trying to do at the bottom

Comment: If there is something common about the tables, then the classes should implement an interface. Then you can use generics to load and modify those columns from any set. `Get<T>() where T:ICommon => db.Set<T>().Select(t => { t.Id, .... });` Then use reflection to call your generic method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   The assumption here is that I know the fields at compile time (t.Id, ...) which I don't as they are calculated at runtime. This is why I am trying to use Linq.Expression to build the lambda in the Select() statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that. However, you can cast the database value to specific types based on discriminators. Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Thanks, I really need to be able to dynamically create DbSets based on the reflected (runtime) type of the table. It appears to have been coded to only use the static type.

Comment: Yes, EfCore entities are hardcoded. The only way you can have dynamic types is to use declare these as objects and then use value converters to serialize and deserialize the objects (this is because polymorphic deserialization is not possible). But if you can elaborate on the actual use case, we might find a solution. Specifically, if you have an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have described the problem in a comment above, but for brevity, I have a DbContext which references an unknown number of tables.  I have a list of column names whose contents act as a key to a lookup table in another system where I retrieve a value. The retrieved value has to be written back into another column in the same table.  The solution would be several lines of code if it were possible to construct a DbSet based on the reflected type of the table (I can construct an entity object containing the PK property and the two fields at runtime).

Comment: Very hard to do that. You can emit EfCore classes at runtime, but complexity is not worth it. As mentioned by @Jeremy Lakeman above, EfCore is about storing domain objects. You are better off using raw SQL. As a side note, you might really want to review the architecture.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at using SQL queries when using SQL SMO however, they get complex fast, and it is difficult to work with the returned data.   In terms of architecture, it is a common thing to do, more so in OO-DBs.  It appears to me to be coding limitation of EF to not support reflection.  I'll consider raising an enhancement request.

Comment: Is there a restriction on using a modern schema less/NoSQL DB like MongoDB?

Comment: Yes, existing system.